# Can I get this Haxe switch statement to be a bit more dynamic?

Tags: haxe

It's not critical but I was wondering. Somewhere in my program I have a switch statement that gets called multiple times with an incremented value, so that all cases should be executed in order. Something like a custom made simple sequencer.

like this:

```
private function sequence_Crush(step:Int):Void
{
    switch(step) {
    case 1: {
        action_loadCueFile();
        seq.next(); //This calls the same function with an increased step
    }
    case 2: {
        action_saveSettings();
        seq.next();
    }

    /// EDIT: Some steps run ASYNC and an event triggers the next step in the sequence
    /// like this:

    case 3: {           
        events.once(ENGINE_EVENTS.cut_all_complete, seq.next);
        cutTracks();
    }
```

**My Question is**, Is there any way to replace the manually written numbers (1,2,3,4) on the cases and use a counter somehow, macros maybe?  I have tried putting a dynamic counter, but the Haxe compiler complains.

What I tried:

```
    var st:Int = 1;
    switch(step) {
    case (st++): { // 1
        action_loadCueFile();
        seq.next();
    }
    case (st++): { // 2
        action_saveSettings();
        seq.next();
    }
    //... etc
```

> **Build halted with errors (haxe.exe)**
>
> **Case expression must be a constant value or a pattern, not an arbitrary expression**

I am targeting JS and using Haxe 3.1.3. I have tried that in actionscript and javascript and it works fine. The reason I want to do that, is that if I want do add or remove a step, I have to re-organize manually every other case number.

*p.s. I know there are other ways to sequence actions in order, but I like this one, as I have everything in one function and it's easy to see the order of execution in one glance*

Thanks for reading :-)

Comment: A switch statement with cases isn't really best for showing the order of execution.  It's not really a guarantee that you're giving the cases in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jason beat me to it by a few minutes...

Case expressions in Haxe must be either constant values or patterns.

But you can accomplish the desired behaviour in a few ways: (a) custom syntax like `$next` with macros; (b) macro conversion into if-else blocks (Jason's answer); (c) without macros and (mis)using pattern guards.

### Custom syntax

A quick and dirty implementation of it follows; it only supports `case $next:` and there are no syntax checks.

When a `case $next:` is found, the macro checks if the previous case pattern was a single constant integer `i` and, in that case, rewrites the pattern to the value of `i + 1`.

Macro implementation:

```
// SequenceSwitch.hx

import haxe.macro.Context;
import haxe.macro.Expr;
import haxe.macro.ExprTools;

class SequenceSwitch {

    public
    macro static function build():Array<Field> {
        var fields = Context.getBuildFields();
        for (f in fields)
            switch (f.kind) {
                case FFun(func) if (func.expr != null):
                    func.expr = ExprTools.map(func.expr, transf);
                case _:
            }
        return fields;
    }

    static function transf(e:Expr):Expr {
        return switch (e.expr) {
            case ESwitch(expr, cases, def):
                var ncases = [];
                var prev:Array<Expr> = null;
                for (c in cases) {
                    var cur = switch (c.values) {
                        case [{ expr : EConst(CIdent("$next")), pos : pos }] if (prev != null):
                            switch (prev) {
                                case [{ expr : EConst(CInt(i)) }]:
                                    var next = { expr : EConst(CInt(Std.string(Std.parseInt(i) + 1))), pos : pos };
                                    { values : [next], guard : c.guard, expr : c.expr };
                                case _:
                                    c;
                            }
                        case _:
                            c;
                    };
                    ncases.push(cur);
                    prev = cur.values;
                }
                { expr : ESwitch(expr, ncases, def), pos : e.pos };
            case _:
                e;
        }
    }

}
```

Usage example:

```
// Text.hx

@:build(SequenceSwitch.build())
class Test {

    static function main() {
        sequenceCrush(1);
    }

    static function sequenceCrush(step:Int) {
        switch (step) {
            case 1:
                trace("do one");
                sequenceCrush(++step);
            case $next:
                trace("do two");
                sequenceCrush(++step);
            case $next:
                trace("do three");
                sequenceCrush(++step);
            case _:
                trace("terminate");
        }
    }

}
```

### No macros/with guards

Similar behaviour could be achieved by (mis)using guards:

```
static function sequenceCrush_guards(step:Int) {
    var st = 1;
    switch (step) {
        case next if (next == st++):
            trace("do one");
            sequenceCrush_guards(++step);
        case next if (next == st++):
            trace("do two");
            sequenceCrush_guards(++step);
        case next if (next == st++):
            trace("do three");
            sequenceCrush_guards(++step);
        case _:
            trace("terminate");
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks! This is the closest answer to what I had in my mind. I really like the macro implementation. I guess I should learn more things about Macros in Haxe as they look quite useful.

Answer (score 2):

In Haxe 3 `switch` changed from the JS/Flash style simple matching, which was really not much more than a chain of if/elseif/else statements, to full on pattern matching, which has many more compile-time features, and one of those limitations is that you can't match against a variable, only against constants.

You could use a chain of `if (step==st++) {} elseif (step==st++) {} else {}` statements for pretty much the same effect.  If you're really really addicted to the `switch` syntax, you could use a macro to get the "classic" switch behaviour.  I happened to write one such macro some time ago, take a look at this GIST:

https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jasononeil/5429516/raw/ad1085082530760aa394765d5cd5ebd61a5dbecb/ClassicSwitch.hx

You could then code like this:

```
class Action
{
        static function main()
        {
                for (currentStep in 0...5) {
                        var i = 0;
                        ClassicSwitch.from(switch (currentStep) {
                                case i++: trace( 'Do step $i' );
                                case i++: trace( 'Do step $i' );
                                case i++: trace( 'Do step $i' );
                                case i++: trace( 'Do step $i' );
                                case i++: trace( 'Do step $i' );
                        });
                }
        }
}
```

Which gives me the output:

> Action.hx:14: Do step 1
>   Action.hx:15: Do step 2
>   Action.hx:16: Do step 3
>   Action.hx:17: Do step 4
>   Action.hx:18: Do step 5

Comment: Thanks! ClassicSwitch seems to do the job, I will try this one as well. The reason I want to stick to switch is mostly for my desire for easy readability. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If all (or most) of your actions are simple function calls you can alternatively use an array of functions:

```
var actions = [sequence_Crush.bind(1), // if you want to avoid action index = step - 1
               action_loadCueFile,
               action_saveSettings,
               ...];

private function sequence_Crush(step:Int):Void
{
    while (step < actions.length)
    {
        actions[step++]();
    }
}
```

You could also keep this recursive (`actions[step++](); if (step < actions.length) { sequence_Crush(step)`).

Comment: Ops... I missed the "I know there are other ways to sequence actions in order, but I like this one" p.s.

Comment: I could do that, but some steps run Async, and I am waiting an event from something else to finish to continue the sequence.

Comment: So that is what the seq.next() is for? If so, you could keep that in: `actions[step](); seq.next();`.

Comment: I agree an array would be nice, OTOH it would be nice knowing if when calling a macro function such as `case macroInc():` it would be possible for it to return a number++, just so we get concrete examples